# How to correctly replace the real part of the FFT?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, fft, complex-numbers

I try to reproduce a data augmentation method, which comes from the paper:

*Qinwei Xu, Ruipeng Zhang, Ya Zhang, Yanfeng Wang and Qi Tian* [**"A Fourier-based Framework for Domain Generalization"**](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2021/papers/Xu_A_Fourier-Based_Framework_for_Domain_Generalization_CVPR_2021_paper.pdf) (CVPR 2021).

It is mentioned in the paper that they set the real part to a constant (the constant in the paper is 20000) to eliminate the amplitude and realize the reconstruction of the image relying only on the phase.
Below is my code:

```
img = process_img("./data/house.jpg", 128)
img_fft = torch.fft.fft2(img, dim=(-2, -1))
amp = torch.full(img_fft.shape, 200000)
img_fft.real = amp
img_ifft = torch.fft.ifft2(img_fft, dim=(-2, -1))

img_ifft = img_ifft.squeeze(0)
img_ifft = img_ifft.transpose(2, 0)

img_ifft = np.array(img_ifft)

cv2.imshow("", img_ifft.real)
```

Among them, the process_img function is only used to convert ndarray to tensor, as shown below:

```
loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
def process_img(img_path, img_size):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_size, img_size))
    img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    img = loader(img)
    img = img.unsqueeze(0)
    return img
```

The first is the original image, the second is the image provided by the paper, and the third is the image generated by my code:

[image: Image comparison]

It can be seen that the images generated by my method are very different from those provided in the paper, and there are some artifacts. Why is there such a result?

Comment: Can you link the paper, too?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the link to the paper, my fault. A Fourier-based Framework for Domain Generalization: https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2021/papers/Xu_A_Fourier-Based_Framework_for_Domain_Generalization_CVPR_2021_paper.pdf

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code and get the same results with different values of constant (20000, 2000, 200, 20, 2 and even 0, so it seems like it doesn't make sense here). And I can't find 20000 in the paper.

Comment: It is stated in the supplementary material of the paper, in "B.2. Single domain evaluations on PACS"

Comment: Note that when you set the real part to 1, part of the effect is that you change the zero frequency component to 1. The zero frequency component is the mean of the image. This is equivalent to subtracting the mean and adding 1 to your input image, which sets a lot of pixels to a negative value (displayed as black). If you contrast-stretch the resulting image, you will see that you have an addition of the image and the image rotated by 180 degrees and inverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing "real"/"imaginary" parts of [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) with "amplitude"/"phase" representation.

Here's the quick guide:
A complex number `z` can be expressed by either a *sum* of its real part `x` and its imaginary part `y`:
`z = x + j y`
Alternatively, once can express the same complex number `z` as a rotated vector with amplitude `r` and an angle `phi`:
`z = r exp(j phi)`
Where `r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` and `phi=atan2(x,y)`.

This image (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)) explain this visually:
[image]

In your code, you replace the "real" part, but in the paper, they suggest replacing the "amplitude".

If you want to replace the amplitude:

```py
const_amp = ... # whatever the constant amplitude you want
new_fft = const_amp * torch.exp(1j * img_fft.angle())

# reconstruct the new image from the modulated Fourier:
img_ifft = torch.fft.ifft2(new_fft, dim=(-2, -1))
```

This results with the following image:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a mistake about the concept of amplitude and phase before, thank you for allowing me to correct this mistake.

Comment: What can I do to replace the phase? I tried to keep the amplitude constant and set the phase to 20000, but the result was a completely black picture. I only changed `new_fft = torch.abs(img_fft) * torch.exp(img_fft.angle() * 20000j)`

Comment: @wenjiezhu what is the meaning of phase 20000?

Comment: I want to replace the phase part and keep the amplitude unchanged.

Comment: @wenjiezhu replace with what? if it's only a constant, you can take the absolute value.

Comment: Ohhhhh, thank you very much! You helped me a lot!